# Key events in the C language

Tags: c, keypress

If you use `getc()` or `scanf()`, you only know what button the user pressed after he pressed enter. Is there a way to get direct keyboard input in the C language?

Also, I'm using gcc on Linux (Raspberry pi).

Comment: Can you use a library? Also, on which OS? Since what you are asking is not portable and non-standard.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux

Comment: Use ncurses. There's no standard C way.

Comment: You need to put the terminal in 'raw' mode.  Use ncurses.

Comment: in windows platform you should use getch() in <conio.h> header.to see how to use in linux go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux

Comment: If you want it really "raw" then you can try reading from files in `/dev/input/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is OS specific (the C99 or C11 standard does not know about the keyboard). On Linux (which I am focusing on in my answer) and Unix, [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) are -for legacy and historical reasons- complex beasts (the kernel is implementing the [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline)), see [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page. For gory details, see also [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) (the raw and noncanonical modes will give you a headache) & [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) & [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html)

<sup>(you could spend months in learning the gory details; I forgot most of them)</sup>

I *strongly* recommend coding with a library such as [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (or [termcap](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html), if you are masochistic enough)

If using a GUI, better use some toolkit like [Qt](http://qt.io/).

To poll a set of file descriptors, use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

See also [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/).

Answer (score 0):

Normally the terminal is in canonical state, which means the key events are only passed to the program after pressing `Enter`. For immediate keyboard response we need raw mode.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76080721/20494412) may help.

More on [raw mode](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html).