# Implementing a KeyPress Event in C with Multiple Threads

Tags: c, multithreading, ncurses, termios, conio

My goal: A thread will wait (busy loop not sleep) until a specific key (lets say 0) is pressed. Each thread has a different key that will trigger that thread to get out of waiting and progress through the commands that follow the wait.

I have tried the following to implement this:

using conio.h and getch() but this is old and doesnt work with gcc anymore. Source: [Why can't I find <conio.h> on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux)

using ncurses.h and getch() but this stops execution while waiting for a keyboard press.
Code I used: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/scanw.html#GETCHCLASS

My current implementation using termios.h:

int main:

```
      //Keypress Event Handler
   struct termios info;
   tcgetattr(0, &info);          /* get current terminal attirbutes; 0 is the file descriptor for stdin */
   info.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;      /* disable canonical mode */
   info.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;          /* wait until at least one keystroke available */
   info.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;         /* no timeout */
   tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &info); /* set immediately */
```

Inside function called by thread (sorry about the indentation):

```
while(stop_wait != 1) 
      {
         //printf("%d\n", temp->currentID);
         ch = getchar();

         if(ch < 0) {
            if (ferror(stdin)) {
               clearerr(stdin);
            }
         }

         switch (ch)
         {
         case 48 :
            if(temp->event == 0) stop_wait = 1;
            break;
         case 49 :
            if(temp->event == 1) stop_wait = 1;
            break;
         case 50 :
            if(temp->event == 2) stop_wait = 1;
            break;
         case 51 :
            if(temp->event == 3) stop_wait = 1;
            break;
         case 52 :
            if(temp->event == 4) stop_wait = 1;
            break;
         }
      }
```

End of main:

```
tcgetattr(0, &info);
info.c_lflag |= ICANON;
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &info);
```

The code above is very similar to what is found here: [Implementing a KeyPress Event in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091191/implementing-a-keypress-event-in-c)

However this doesn't work the correct way I want it to. I have an input file specifying which keys will trigger the stop_wait to be changed to 1. Thread 1 will be triggered by pressing 1 on the keyboard (49 in ascii) and Thread 2 will be triggered by pressing 2 on the keyboard (50 in ascii). The problem with the current implementation is that 2 will not trigger without 1 being triggered. As shown below (the Main() statement shows the end of execution ignore what it says):
[image]

Can I get any advice / help with this issue?

Comment: Why don't you just dedicate one thread to keyboard input, and use getch(), in a loop, and everytime a character is pressed set a state variable or a flag or something and each other 'free running' thread  can poll the state to detect that a key was pressed and see what key and respond accordingly?

Comment: A lot of schemes to decide how to fine tune it. For example so no keys are dropped.  Potentially even each thread could have a fifo and the 'kbd inpt/dispatch' thread could queue a message to the appropriate thread it needs to signal. In that scheme (and however you implemented the fifo), you could ensure that you would never miss a key stroke.  For example if thread 1 needed to do something for every 'a' press it would never miss a keypress

Comment: I didnt look at it like that. Thanks! I will try to implement it and see but I think that will definitely work.

Comment: It might not be exactly what your situation needs, but I did create a working example (answer below). You could tweak the  polling interval (use a smaller wait than 1 section, by instead of `sleep()`, using `usleep()`). And you could mess with the queueing strategy. But it's worth testing the code IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the look. I just updated the answer. I forgot to free() the memory allocated, so I just now added that line. Otherwise it  will leak memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multi-threaded approach I mentioned in the comments, that has a separate thread to fetch and enqueue keys,  being designed not to drop keys, isn't trivial.  It requires some C skills and some UNIX knowledge.   I implemented a working skeleton that runs, so you can see what's involved.

To test this, save the file as, let's say,  dispatch.c

```
$ cc -o dispatch dispatch.c
$ ./dispatch
```

Sample output:

> <sup>$ ./dispatch
>
>   Key 'a' pressed...
>
>   ... Thread T3 pulled key 'a' from queue
>
>   ... Thread T1 pulled key 'a' from queue
>
>   ... Thread T2 pulled key 'a' from queue
>
>   Key 'b' pressed...
>
>   ... Thread T2 pulled key 'b' from queue
>
>   ... Thread T1 pulled key 'b' from queue
>
>   Key 'c' pressed...
>
>   ... Thread T3 pulled key 'c' from queue
>
>   ... Thread T1 pulled key 'c' from queue
>
>   Key 'd' pressed...
>
>   ... Thread T2 pulled key 'd' from queue
>
>   ... Thread T3 pulled key 'd' from queue
>
>   Key 'z' pressed...
>
>   ... Thread T2 pulled key 'z' from queue
>
>   ... Thread T1 pulled key 'z' from queue
>
>   ... Thread T3 pulled key 'z' from queue</sup>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

typedef struct keyQueue {
    struct keyQueue *next;
    char key;
} keyQueue_t;

typedef struct ThreadInfo {
    pthread_t tid;           /* thread id */
    pthread_mutex_t kqmutex; /* protects key queue from race condition between threads */
    keyQueue_t kqhead;       /* input keys queued to this thread */
    char *keys;              /* keys this thread responds to */
    char *name;              /* name of this thread */
} threadInfo_t;

static struct termios origtc, newtc;

threadInfo_t threads[] = { 
    { 0, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, { NULL, '\0' }, "abcez", "Thread T1" },
    { 0, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, { NULL, '\0' }, "abdfz", "Thread T2" },
    { 0, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, { NULL, '\0' }, "acdgz", "Thread T3" }
};

void *service(void *arg) {
    char key;
    threadInfo_t *t = &threads[(int)arg];    // get pointer to thread
    for(;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&t->kqmutex);     // lock other threads out while we tamper 
        key = '\0';                          // initialize key to NULL
        if (t->kqhead.next != NULL) {        // Anything queued up for us?
            keyQueue_t *kq = t->kqhead.next; // if so get ptr to key pkt
            key = kq->key;                   // fetch key from pkt
            t->kqhead.next = kq->next;       // Point to next key in queue (or NULL if no more queued up).
            free(kq);
        }  
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&t->kqmutex);   // unlock key queue
        if (key != '\0') {                   // if we got a key, log it
            printf("... %s pulled key '%c' from queue\n", t->name, key);
        }
        // ⇓ usleep() probably more practical as 1-sec too long for most cases
        sleep(1);                            // sleep so we don't loop too fast eating CPU
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {

    /* Fire up threads */
    for (long i = 0; i < sizeof (threads) / sizeof (threadInfo_t); i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i].tid, NULL, service, (void *)i) < 0) {
            perror("pthread_create()");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    tcgetattr(0, &origtc);                         // get orig tty settings
    newtc = origtc;                                // copy them
    newtc.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;                      // put in '1 key mode'
    newtc.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;                        // turn off echo

    for(;;) {
        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &newtc);             // echo off 1-key read mode
        char c = getchar();                        // get single key immed.
        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &origtc);            // settings back to normal
        printf("Key '%c' pressed...\n", c);        // show user what we got
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (threads) / sizeof (threadInfo_t); i++) {
            threadInfo_t *t = &threads[i];         // get shorthand ptr to thread
            if (strchr(t->keys, c) != NULL) {      // this thread listens for this key
                pthread_mutex_lock(&t->kqmutex);   // lock other threads out while we tamper 
                keyQueue_t *kq = calloc(sizeof (struct keyQueue), 1); // allocate pkt
                kq->key = c;                       // stash key there
                keyQueue_t *kptr = &t->kqhead;     // get pointer to queue head
                while(kptr->next != NULL)          // find first empty slot
                    kptr = kptr->next;
                kptr->next = kq;                   // enqueue key packet to thread
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&t->kqmutex); // unlock key queue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code starts three threads, t1, t2, t3, which each have a 'key queue' structure on them, as well as a `char *` field `keys`. `keys` is a string containing the characters (keys) the thread is 'interested in'.

The keyboard keys listed in the string are duplicated in the threads string so that one key can be consumed by more than one thread in some cases. For example, all the threads listen to 'a' and 'z', two threads listen to 'b', another two to 'c', another pair of threads are interested in 'd', and finally 'e', 'f', and 'g' have only one thread listening, respectively.

The main loop reads keys without echo and captures keys immediately (e.g. without the user having to hit return).  When a key is entered, it loops through the thread info to find out which threads are interested in the pressed key and enqueues the key (in a packet) to the respective thread(s).

The threads are in their own loop, sleeping one second in between loops. When they wake up they check their queue to see if there are any keys queued. If there are they pull it from the queue and say they pulled that key from the queue.

Because of the delay in each thread's polling/work loop (e.g. before the threads wake up and check their respective queues), there's time for you to enter multiple things on the keyboard to get queued up to the threads, and then the threads will dequeue them the enqueue keys one at a time at 1 second intervals.

In real life the program would use a much shorter sleep, but would put *something* in there to keep each thread from needlessly hogging a lot of CPU time.

Kind of fun to run it and see it in action.

*Note: `calloc()` is used instead of `malloc()` because unlike `malloc()`, `calloc()` initializes the memory returned to all 0's. It's a nice trick.